# Symfony2 + Nginx 404 not found

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm having trouble configuring Symfony2 with nginx

I installed symfony2 like this

> php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /var/www/symf

everything went smoothly, when i'm on the config page no erros
[image]

but when i click Configure online or Buypass config i'm landing on nginx 404 NOT FOUND

here is the config file

```
upstream phpfcgi {
server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
listen 80;

server_name localhost;
root /var/www/symf/web;

error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony2.error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony2.access.log;

# strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

location / {
    index app.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
}
}
```

Note : i noticed when clicking buypass i'm landing on a link like ....symf/web/app_dev.php/
removing last / allow me to reach the page but got and error
[image]
clicking ok -> 404 no found

i'm i missing something ?

parameters.yml

```
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: *****
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: fr
secret: ******
debug_toolbar: true
debug_redirects: false
use_assetic_controller: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that part

```
# strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
```

You are already rewritting here after the `try file` which is how it should be done

```
location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}
```

And ofc make sure you reload your nginx service

Comment: thank you but still cannot reach the page, 404 not found

Comment: You are installing on your local computer right not on a server ? Else you should try removing the locahost reference from the server_name directive and replacing it with 'your-domain.com' or '' for default. If that doesn't work we need more info on your php setup (ie: php5-fpm).

Comment: on a server yes, not locally, tried putting server_name to default, same, what exactly do you need ? php-fpm.conf file ?

Comment: @MuiMui not locally?? it wont work. if look at config folder there are `routing.yml` and `routing_dev.yml` which are responsible for local and production instances of your project.. Also, in prod version you can simply set you configuration in parameters.yml file

Comment: @xurshid29 my parameters.yml file was configured during the installation i edited first post to show you the config.

Comment: @MuiMui ok, just create a route and test it then, it should work. but dev config won't work on prod version

Comment: the routes seems to be created routing.yml                              `_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator


# AcmeDemoBundle routes (to be removed)
_acme_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to suggest somthing without knowing about your server configuration, but here is my working config, which works very fine (for nginx-php-fpm), may be it helps you:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name my_site.dev *.my_site.dev;
    root /var/www/my_site.dev/public_html/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/my_site_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my_site_access.log;

    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # Deny all . files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        send_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Statics
    location /(bundles|media) {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;

        # Font files
        #if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
        #       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        #}

        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was with nginx, switching to apache2 and worked instantly

EDIT : if anyone has a clue of what is going on with nginx, is the conf file wrong ? i would like to know

Comment: This may sound stupid but did you happen to try restarting nginx after you made changes to the config file?